# Range of the transformation $T$ such that $T(v_1)=w_2,T(v_2)=T(v_3)=w_1+w_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> With bases $v_1,v_2,v_3$ and $w_1,w_2,w_3$, suppose $T(v_1)=w_2$ and $T(v_2)=T(v_3)=w_1+w_3$. $T$ is a linear transformation. Find a vector that is not in the column space of $A$. Find a combination of $w$'s that is not in the range of the transformation $T$.

The solution given is $(1,0,0)\notin C(A)$, which is fine, and $w_1\notin range(T)$

But how come we can say $w_1\notin range(T)$ ?
$$
T(v_1)=w_2\\
T(v_2)=w_1+w_3\\
T(v_3)=w_1+w_3\\
$$
The matrix for the given linear transformation is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
$(1,0,0)\notin C(A)$ which is clear. but how do we conclude that $w_1\notin range(T)$ ?

$\color{blue}{\text{Can we equate $(1,0,0)$ to $w_1$ ?}}$

**What I know**

In the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ for the given vector $\vec{x}=x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3$
$$
T(\vec{x})=x_1T(e_1)+x_2T(e_2)+x_3T(e_3)=\begin{bmatrix}T(e_1)&T(e_2)&T(e_3)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=A\vec{x}
$$

If the input basis is $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ and output basis is $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ then $\vec{x}=y_1v_1+y_2v_2+y_3v_3$
$$
T(\vec{x})=x_1[T(v_1)]_w+x_2[T(v_2)]_w+x_3[T(v_3)]_w=\begin{bmatrix}[T(v_1)]_w&[T(v_2)]_w&[T(v_3)]_w\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=A_{v\to w}\vec{x}
$$

Comment: Your last sentence makes no sense.

Comment: @QuantumSpace my doubt is how come $w_1$ is not in the range of T from the fact that $(1,0,0)\notin C(A)$ ?

Comment: @QuantumSpace is there any justification that we can equate $w_1$ with $(1,0,0)$ ?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. $w_1$ is not specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that $(1,0,0)=w_1$... what else could it be?

Assume $\mathbf{v}:=a\cdot v_1+b\cdot v_2+c\cdot v_3$ is in your first vector space and solve:

$T(\mathbf{v})=w_1$.

If you are unsure about why $w_1=(1,0,0)$, but accept the matrix representation for $T$ (which is with respect to $w_1=(1,0,0)$ by the way), I can ask you to solve

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 1 
\\ 1 & 0 & 0 
\\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\0\end{array}\right],$$
and you will see that $(1,0,0)$ is not in the range of the matrix representation of $T$...

I don't really understand your confusion to be honest... if you choose the basis $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ for your target vector space, then you can choose $w_1=(1,0,0)$ and if you do that you get the matrix representation for $T$ that you have... how else can you get that matrix representation without making such a choice?

Comment: $T(v)=w_1$ does not have a solution since $b+c=1$ requires another term $w_3$ on the RHS. Okay this proves it. but why'd anyone assume that $w_1=(1,0,0)$ without knwing $w_1\notin range(T)$ ?

Comment: It is standard enough kind of notation. In fact you assume it in your matrix representation of $T$.

Comment: I mean $w_1$ can  be from any other basis right ?. Are you saying that becasue $(1,0,0)\notin C(A)$ and the first standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $(1,0,0)$ we assumed $w_1=(1,0,0)$ ?

Comment: Where is it assumed $w_1=(1,0,0)$, sorry I am still confused ?

Comment: Where did you get the matrix representation of $T$? Answer that and you will see $w_1=(1,0,0)$.

Comment: Given input basis is $v_i$ and output basis as $w_i$ then $j^{th}$ column of $T$ is the linear transformation of the $j^{th}$ input basis written interms of the output bases, right ?, as mentioned in updated OP.

Comment: $T(v_1)=w_2=0w_1+1w_2+0w_3$ so column $1$ of $A$ becomes $(0,1,0)$, but it doesn't mean that $w_2=(0,1,0)$ right ?

Comment: I don't really understand your confusion to be honest... more in the above.

Comment: Absolutely it means $w_2=(0,1,0)$.

Comment: I also don't understand why you use the term "change of basis matrix" here.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy I believe you are confusing the OP very hard. $w_1$ need not be equal to $(1,0,0)$. What is true is that its coordinate w.r.t. the base $\{w_1, w_2, w_3\}$ are equal to $(1,0,0)$. Writing $w_1 = (1,0,0)$ is abuse of notation. Instead you should write something like $[w_1]= (1,0,0)$. This may be obvious to you, but absolutely not to a beginner in linear algebra.

Comment: @QuantumSpace surely writing down that matrix representation is implicitly assuming that $(1,0,0)$ is in fact equal to $w_1$?

Comment: (Appreciate what you are saying about is being a representation wrt some basis)

Comment: Yes, you say it right: 'implicitely'. I have no doubt that you are perfectly aware what's happening, I was just pointing out that this identification (because essentially you are identifying the vector w.r.t. the chosen basis) may be non-obvious to the OP and it might be better to make it a bit explicit. Cheers!

Comment: @QuantumSpace you first 2 sentenses is the way I could manage to look at it. $T(v_1)=w_2=0w_1+1w_2+0w_3$. So the coordinate of $w_2$ w.r.t the basis $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ is $(0,1,0)$. But, how can this picture implies $(1,0,0)\notin C(A)$ and $w_1=(1,0,0)$ implies $w_1\notin range(T)$ ?

Comment: Let me ask you a question first. What is the matrix of the transformation $T$ with respect to the chosen bases?

Comment: @QuantumSpace I already asked this above and it did not seem to help. I do not understand how we are failing the OP.

Comment: @QuantumSpace $A=[[T(v_1)]_{w},[T(v_2)]_{w},[T(v_3)]_{w}]$ where $[T(v_j)]_{w}$ is the transformation of $v_j$ in the basis of $w_i$. $[T(v_1)]_{w}=w_2=(0,1,0)$, $[T(v_2)]_{w}=w_1+w_3=(1,0,1)$, $[T(v_3)]_{w}=w_1+w_3=(1,0,1)$. $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$, right ?

Comment: @ss1729 Yes, that's the correct matrix. Do you understand that the set $\{Av : v \in \mathbb{R}^3\}$ gives every vector in the image of $T$, when expressed in coordinates w.r.t. the basis $\{w_1, w_2, w_3\}?$

Comment: @QuantumSpace well I never thought about it. $A$ is the transformation matrix from $v_i$ basis to $w_i$ basis. So that means it should transform every vector $v\in R^3$ to every vector in the image of $T$ written in terms of $w_i$ basis ?

Comment: Basically yes! More precisely, if $v$ has coordinates $(a,b,c)$ with respect to $v_1, v_2, v_3$, then $Tv$ will have coordinates $A(a,b,c)^T$ with respect to $w_1, w_2, w_3$.

Comment: I think I get it. So from the matrix for the transformation its $C(A)=span((0,1,0),(1,0,1))$, but here $(0,1,0)=T(v_1)=w_2=0w_1+1w_2+0w_3$ is the image of $v_1$ w.r.t the basis $w_i$, not the standard basis. So $(0,1,0)\in C(A)$ which implies $w_2\in range(T)$ both the same thing. and similar argument can be made for $w_1\notin range(T)$, correct ?

Comment: @QuantumSpace could you please comment on my last statement ?

Comment: @ss1729 This does not quite show that $w_1 \notin range(T)$. You have to show that $A(a,b,c)^T = (1,0,0)^T$ has no solutions, as explained in the answer above.

Comment: @QuantumSpace i mean my last statement clarifies what is meant by $w_1=(1,0,0)$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. But you also write "which implies $w_2 \in range(T)$. This is literally given.

Comment: @QuantumSpace sorry about "which implies", what I meant to say was, $(0,1,0)\in C(A)$ and $w_2\in range(T)$ both the same thing, due to the statement before it in that comment.

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct.